# I am accessing current instant of Lync running in my local computer in window service

Tags: lync

I am accessing current instance of Lync running in my local computer by window service.

```
 public static LyncClient lyncClient;
 {
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

               lyncClient = LyncClient.GetClient(); // I am getting error here at run time

         }
}
```

I installed this service and when i was running this service, I got error message "The MyService service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or program."

I checked Event Viewer. It showed following exception:

Service cannot be started. Microsoft.Lync.Model.ClientNotFoundException: The host process is not running
   at Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.EnsureOI()
   at Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.GetClient(Boolean sideBySideLync)
   at TestService.ACD.OnStart(String[] args) in g:\TestService\TestService\ACD.cs:line 53
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)

But i have signed in Lync Client.

pls give me a solution to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you using the correct SDK?  I expect that the 2013 Client SDK may throw this exception on a 2010 client, although I know for a fact that its fine to use the 2010 SDK with the 2013 client.

Comment: Yes. I used correct SDK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure you're running the service as the same user that's running the lync.exe process (probably yourself). If you're running the service as another identity (such as Network Service) it won't be able to access the lync.exe process, and will give you that error.

-tom

Comment: I got this error when running an executable as a scheduled task. If I set the security option to "Run whether user is logged on or not," I get the error, but it works okay if I choose "Run only when user is logged on."